# I can't configure Varnish with Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

i am setting varnish
from this url https://github.com/nexylan/varnish-prestashop/blob/master/vcl/varnish4.vcl

and the error I'm having is I can't enter the prestashop admin and the other problem is that when I add products to the cart it doesn't save them

Thank You.

```
# disable cookies for static files
    if (req.url ~ "\.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|pdf)$" && ! (req.url ~ "\.(php)") ) {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        return (hash);
    }

    # pipe on weird http methods
    if (req.method !~ "^GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|TRACE|OPTIONS|DELETE$") {
        return(pipe);
    }

    if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "^/?mylogout=")) {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        return (pass);
    }

    #we should not cache any page for Prestashop backend
    if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "^/admin")) {
        return (pass);
    }

    #we should not cache any custom directory
    if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "^/custom")) {
        return (pass);
    }

    #we should not cache any page for customers
    if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "^/authentification" || req.url ~ "^/mon-compte")) {
        return (pass);
    }

    #we should not cache any page for customers
    if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "^/informations" || req.url ~ "^/unt.php")) {
        return (pass);
    }

    #we should not cache any page for sales
    if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "^/commande" || req.url ~ "^/historique")) {
        return (pass);
    }

    #we should not cache any page for sales
    if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "^/adresse" || req.url ~ "^/order-detail.php")) {
        return (pass);
    }

    #we should not cache any page for sales
    if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "^/order-confirmation.php" || req.url ~ "^/order-return.php")) {
        return (pass);
    }

    #we should not cache any module
    if (req.method == "GET" && req.url ~ "^/module") {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }
```